# Postgresql. Ошибка в Insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

Составил запрос:

```
INSERT INTO db.indicators
(id_indicator, indicator_name)
SELECT src.id_indicator, src.indicator_name
FROM tmp.indicators AS src
ON CONFLICT (id_indicator)
DO UPDATE 
SET indicator_name=EXCLUDED.indicator_name;
```

В результате выдает ошибку:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ON"
```

Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: INSERT .. SELECT вроде как не поддерживает ON CONFLICT. Вводите дополнительные ограничения в SELECT-части.

Comment: [MERGE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html)

Comment: @Akina Вообще поддерживается. И даже синтаксис правильный. У меня кричит что таблиц нет. А если например слово conflict по другому написать то тогда синтакс еррор дает, что логично

Comment: У меня ощущение, что проблема в том средстве с помощью которого запрос выполняют, оно что то пытается трактовать по своему и скармливает postgresql не так

Comment: Работаю в DBeaver последняя версия. Postgresql также одна из последних версий.